# how to change container size to 960px in bootstrap for 1920px large screens

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

In 1200px devices I can change container size to 960px, but my notebook has Full HD screen 1920px..* and

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px!important;
}
```

doesn't work for my notebook

Anybody knows what to do?

Comment: Check out [@media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: if u mean like this
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}
it doesn't work :(

Comment: @May even if you add !important?

Comment: again the same result 1170 px :(

Comment: Why not use a customized version of Bootstrap? You can easily set the container sizes: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes or go ahead and download the source, edit these same variables, and recompile the less.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  .container {
     max-width: 960px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work for this large devices ,

Comment: @May instead of `only screen` try `only all`

Comment: @May Hmm... if you don't import bootstrap from a CDN you could try putting it inside the bootstrap CSS file itself. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also check to make sure there is no other css file with @media styles canceling out this one. For example:

```
<link href="stylesheet_1.css" />
<link href="stylesheet_2.css" />
```

If you have `.container { max-width: 960px!important; }` in `stylesheet_1.css`, make sure you don't have something like `.container { max-width: 1170px!important; }`  canceling it out in `stylesheet_2.css`. It happens.

Comment: I kept order, because in other computers <1920px it works
I think I should set or some customization or js ?

Comment: Maybe your display is bigger than 1920px? Some Apple notebook displays are as wide as 2560px or even 3840px. To check, open Apple menu > About This Mac > More Info > Graphics/Displays.

Or just try: 

`@media only screen and (max-width: 3850px)`

Comment: Or use `min-width: 1024px` (for any window wider than 1024px)

Answer (score 0):

this way is true too

.container {max-width: 960px;}

P.S  my problem was my browser, I reinstall it and everything is working 
thank you for your helps ;)